# Call Function By Its Offset In C

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering

I am trying to dynamically load a shared library with `dlopen` and call a **non exported** function by its offset in the library's binary file. However, I cannot figure out exactly how? I know the function's signature though.

```
void *lib_ref = dlopen("libany.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (lib_ref != NULL) {
    const char *(*Ref_0000ABCC)(int *, const char *);
    Ref_0000ABCC = dlsym(lib_ref, "0000ABCC");
    if (Ref_0000ABCC != NULL) {
        int ok;
        Ref_0000ABCC(&ok, "Something");
    } else {
        // could not get reference
    }
    dlclose(lib_ref);
} else {
        // could not load library
}
```

Can anyone please help?

**EDIT:** I assembled below code, it throws `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1`:

```
void *lib_ref = dlopen("libany.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (lib_ref != NULL) {
    Dl_info lib_info;
    dladdr(lib_ref, &lib_info);
    size_t lib_addr = (size_t) lib_info.dli_fbase;
    size_t func_addr = lib_addr + 0x0000ABCC;
    const char *(*Ref_0000ABCC)(int *, const char *) = (const char *(*)(int *, const char *))(func_addr);
    if (Ref_0000ABCC != NULL) {
        int ok;
        const char *result = Ref_0000ABCC(&ok, "Something");
    } else {
        // could not find reference
    }
    dlclose(lib_ref);
} else {
    // could not load library
}
```

Comment: Is `0x0000ABCC` just a guess or a value you've determined somehow? If you call random code it's going to explode.

Comment: You realize, of course, that by not exporting the function in question, the shared library's author was expressing the opinion that you should *not* be able to call it.

Comment: First of all, you're checking the wrong pointer. Chances of some pointer + 0x0000ABCC being NULL are minuscule. Where are you checking the return value of `dladdr` though... and aren't you supposed to provide in a *symbol* from that shared object, not the handle to the loaded `.so`.

Comment: What happens when a new version of the library appears?  This all sounds a bit dodgy:(

Comment: @tadman I found the address 0x0000ABCC from IDA.

Comment: This seems like the wrong way to reference a library function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easy if the library `libany.so` you are dealing with has an exported symbol. If the library exports a **function** named `int some_exported_func(const char *)`, you can check **its** offset in *IDA* which (for e.g.,) we suppose is `0x000075AC`. The function you are looking for is at `0x0000ABCC` as per IDA. So, now you can calculate the difference between these 2 offsets, find the named function at runtime and then add that difference to its offset to get to the desired function.

Example code is below:

```
void *lib_ref = dlopen("libany.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (lib_ref != NULL) {
    int (*func_named)(const char *) = dlsym(lib_ref, "some_exported_func");
    if (func_named != NULL) {
        Dl_info func_info;
        dladdr(func_named, &func_info);
        size_t addr_named = (size_t) func_info.dli_saddr;
        int difference = 0x0000ABCC - 0x000075AC;
        size_t addr_ABCC = addr_named + difference;
        const char *(*func_ABCC)(int *, const char *) = (const char *(*)(int *, const char *))(addr_ABCC);
        if (func_ABCC != NULL) {
            int ok;
            const char *result = func_ABCC(&ok, "Something");
        } else {
            // could not find reference
        }
    }
    dlclose(lib_ref);
} else {
    // could not load library
}
```